How to enable App Shortcuts in MacOS Sonoma?
I upgraded my MacOS to Sonoma but my App Shortcuts that were already defined are not working.  All of my shortcuts are per application (none are All Applications)  and when I view the menus in the application, the menu items show my keyboard shortcut.  But the shortcuts don't work. The application default keyboard shortcut does work.
For example, the application default is: ⌃ Control + V, then I define it as: ⌘ Command + C.
In the application, I see:

, but that keyboard shortcut doesn't work. The application default keyboard shortcut DOES work: ⌘ Command + C.
Restarting doesn't help.  Is there way to force these shortcuts to respond in Sonoma? Or is there a new setting that I'm missing?
